# Materialize CSS Transparent Gradient Overlay on Card Image

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to overlay a transparent gradient to an image card from the Materialize CSS framework. The consensus that I've found online suggests that this should be easily achieved by placing the `img` tag into a `div` and applying a gradient background to said `div`. Then simply moving the `z-index` of the `img` tag behind the gradient, thus overlaying it.

However, I'm running into some issue with this approach. For some reason there there seems to be no transparency on my overlay meaning only the gradient can be seen, not the image behind. I presume it's something to do with the materialize framework, is there some way I can work around it?

[JSFiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/fo300jjh/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image postergrad">
                <div class="postergrad">
                    <img class="poster" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/horrormovies/images/e/e1/28-Days-Later-Posters.jpg">
                </div>
                <span class="card-title">28 Days Later</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.postergrad { 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(     startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.poster {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is not a possible way to achieve the desired effect, as the image is a child of the gradient div.

Only if you give opacity put your image to a higher zIndex and give it an opacity, this will work.

Otherwise, you can change the CSS to put the gradient on `::after` of the `div.postergrad`, give it a `content: ' '`, `position: absolute` and align the overlay above the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood.

You can't set an image in the HTML behind it's own wrappers background..background is background.

You can use the wrappper to create a pseudo-element overlay.

```css
.postergrad {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.postergrad::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.poster {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m4 l3">
    <div class="card hoverable">
      <div class="card-image">
        <div class="postergrad">
          <img class="poster" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/horrormovies/images/e/e1/28-Days-Later-Posters.jpg">
        </div>
        <span class="card-title">28 Days Later</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you! Not sure I entirely grasp the way it's actually fixing the issue though. What does `::after` achieve in this instance that having the background properties applied to the main wrapper  doesn't?

Comment: As I said, you can't put anything **under** a wrapper's background...nothing at all. No Z-index in the world can do that. So you need something **on top** of the image. This can be another div but then that's extra HTML just for styling and that's not good practice, so we use a pseudo-element instead.